# How to convert a string in the desired manner?

Tags: python, string

I have the following output:

```
[('A', 'A'), ('A', 'C')]
```

But the expected output is:

```
AA 
AC
```

I would like to print "AA" and "AC" on separate lines.

I have been unable to do it.

Comment: without the code that generates that output we really can't help you

Comment: Please share your code with us. Maybe we could modify your code itself to get the desired output.

Comment: Did an answer below help? Feel free to accept an answer (green tick on left), or ask for clarification.

Answer (score 1):

Use `str.join`

**Ex:**

```
l = [('A', 'A'), ('A', 'C'), ('A', 'H'), ('A', 'K'), ('C', 'C'), ('C', 'H'), ('C', 'K'), ('H', 'H'), ('H', 'K'), ('K', 'K')]
print(["".join(i) for i in l])
print("\n".join(["".join(i) for i in l]))  #If you need it in separate lines
```

**Output:**

```
['AA', 'AC', 'AH', 'AK', 'CC', 'CH', 'CK', 'HH', 'HK', 'KK']
AA
AC
AH
AK
CC
CH
CK
HH
HK
KK
```

Comment: I am using Python 3 version

Comment: What is not working? any error? This works in python3

Comment: The output I am getting is [(AA),(AC)] and so on....Again should I wanted the output as AA AC (These both should be in separate lines)

Comment: Did you try the second line `print("\n".join(["".join(i) for i in l]))`

Comment: Thanks a lot....I have been trying this for hours... Finally you helped me......Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Do the following to get all the tuples merged as strings on separate lines:

```
for i in range(len(l)):
    print (''.join(l[i]))
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is to iterate your list:

```
lst = [('A', 'A'), ('A', 'C')]

for item in lst:
    print(''.join(item))
```